# Replace Heat Exchanger on 15 year old furnace?

Tags: hvac, repair, furnace

I've got two Carrier furnaces in my basement; 90% efficiency / 100k BTU and 60k BTU. Both are 15 years old.

These Carrier furnaces are known to have fault secondary heat exchangers and Carrier (via a settled class action) will replace the heat exchangers and cover most of the labor.

The 100k BTU furnace is kicking sulfur smelling exhaust and this winter has just started tripping the flame switch...  so it sure looks / smells like the secondary heat exchanger is failing.  I've got too reset the furnace once every few days at this point, and I'm getting paranoid about carbon monoxide so action needs to be taken.

I called up my local Carrier dealer, and for $300 they will replace both secondary and primary heat exchanger in each furnace under the Carrier warranty.

My local HVAC guy, I think would drop in a new equivalent furnace for $3,000.

Has anyone ever actually fixed their heat exchanger and coaxed out a few more years of their furnace?  I would not spend $1,000 to fix a heat exchanger on a 15 year old furnace, but $300 under warranty is awfully tempting vs. a $3,000 replacement (so actually, I'm going to have the replace all the heat exchangers in both furnaces, for $600... even though the 60k BTU doesn't have any issues right now).

I NEVER FIX THINGS LIKE THIS, but am I crazy not to give it a shot on Carrier's dime?   The inducer motor and blower motor don't seem that crazy to replace if needed and I can replace the control board if I had too.

---

**UPDATE:**

Furnace guys showed up, and pulled apart these Carrier furnaces.  Primary heat exchangers were pristine;  secondary heat exchangers were clogged and defective.   No charge whatsoever and the installer said no need to change the primaries because they'll likely last the life of the furnace!   If you have a Carrier find an official Carrier dealer and ask them to change the secondaries!

You are in fact not crazy....   I think the secondary exchangers cost like $1,200 independent of install costs (my installer took about 1.5 hrs per furnace, but he said when he started it took him 6 hrs per furnace!).

It sounds to me like it would be $1,500 per furnace for a fix, which I would be really marginal on versus a new furnace.  (Total quoted cost covered by warranty was $3,000 per furnace!)  Installer guy thought the secondary exchangers are good for 5 - 10 years until they will clog and die again.  If the furnace makes it that long, it's definently due for a replacement.

Shout out to Elgin Sheet Metal in Elgin, Illinois.   These guys are totally honest and legit.   When the old furnaces go,  I'm giving them a call for the full stack in the basement + outside AC.

Comment: Take the deal, but also install a CO alarm. Actually, do the second part first.

Comment: Yeah...   Home Depot delivered the CO + smoke and I put it in last weekend!   For my own sanity in the basement at least!

Comment: You want CO detectors near the bedrooms. Sure, have one in the basement as well, but it's lighter than air and is good at "the sleep you never wake up from" method of offing you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going to VtC this as opinion based, as the "am I crazy to replace on Carrier's dime" is really only going to generate opinions. Of course, you also ask for experience with heat exchanger replacement and additional life span, which makes it two questions and too broad... My _opinion_, though, is to replace the furnace for $3k, though. I just replaced furnace & AC this summer and it cost me $9k and I got a "good deal" from a family member! (Also, the reason pricing questions - which this isn't - are off topic.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate -- free of charge, furnaces are running like rockstars.   The primaries were in perfect shape.   Pretty much I have a control board, inducer, and blower that could go out at this point.   This turned out to be basically a new furnace under warranty!